# Equivalent of "where not exists" in MDX?

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

Apologies if this is redundant, I have done some searching but my inexperience with MDX has made it hard for me to apply to my case.

I've got an OLAP service which has data that looks like this:

[image: sample data]

I want to get the **entire contents** of baskets that contain Eggs. So the end result in this example would return the set consisting of basket 1 and 3.

Now, I know how to do this in SQL with an analytic function or `where exists ()` clause, but I cannot figure out how to do it in MDX.

This set definition will be used to filter/pivot an Excel OLAP pivot, so the measures are really irrelevant so long as the set definition is set up.

Thanks!